# PostgreSQL 10 SELECT WHERE statements

Tags: postgresql, range

I am currently new to PostgreSQL and learning on version 10.14. Was working on SELECT commands using the WHERE operator and confused while using the NOT option.

Objective: Retrieve data between a particular range; "marks less than equal to 35 & more than equal 60".

Issue: the difference between the two syntaxes, as results are different?

```
SELECT name FROM science_class WHERE science_marks not between 35 and 60;   
SELECT name FROM science_class WHERE science_marks<=35 AND science_marks>=60;
```

Thank you,
Hermes Schema

Answer (score 2):

These queries below should give the same results: the data *outside* of the range. Note that [`BETWEEN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) operator includes the endpoints. Also, you need `OR`, not `AND` in the second statement:

```
SELECT name FROM science_class WHERE science_marks NOT BETWEEN 35 AND 60;   
SELECT name FROM science_class WHERE science_marks < 35 OR science_marks > 60;
```

To include the data *in* the range, rather than outside of the range, use any of these:

```
SELECT name FROM science_class WHERE science_marks BETWEEN 35 AND 60;   
SELECT name FROM science_class WHERE science_marks >= 35 AND science_marks <= 60;
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost have the right idea.

TL;DR : your second query should be `SELECT name FROM science_class WHERE science_marks < 35 OR science_marks > 60;`

1. It should be OR instead of AND because it should meet either one of those condition. With And, both condition must be met which is impossible
2. When you say NOT BETWEEN 35 AND 60, you are excluding the 35 and 60 so you should use < or > and not <= or >=

Comment: that is correct! I am wanting to exclude by using the NOT BETWEEN operator. I am using the OR and not AND function which is my confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Lower & upper ranges are included in `between` and you've included them in your exclusion (if you see what I mean).  Should be `<35` or `>60` to be equivalent.